# Why the same properties file was found at startup but not later in Spring Java app?

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have a "applicationContext.xml" file which has the following lines :

```
<bean id="jdbcPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/properties/support-center.properties</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

The app started fine. But when I called :

ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

It gave an error message :

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/properties/support-center.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

So, I thought maybe if I change it to `<value>support-center.properties</value>` and put the property file in the same dir as applicationContext.xml , it might find it, but no, the whole app won't even start, and said it can't find support-center.properties

Now I'm confused, because the original setting : /WEB-INF/properties/support-center.properties
was correct, it started the app with this setting, but why when I called :

ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

it couldn't find the property ? Same setting, found at start up, but now later. Why ?

Edit :

Thanks to the answer, it worked [ with minor correction ], it should be :

```
<bean id="jdbcPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value ="classpath:support-center.properties" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What does startup consist of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that support-center.properties is in the same directory, or in you classpath
try using

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location" value ="classpath:support-center.properties" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml")` is called, it will keep use the current path (classpath) as the location.
So /WEB-INF/properties/support-center.properties is not existing under classpath folder.

You can eith add `/WEB-INF/properties/support-center.properties` to classpath or just copy the file to the same location as applicationContext.xml, then use:

```
classpath:support-center.properties
```